# What is the Cleartool command to undo check out if it is identical?

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

I checkout a powershell file and signing it if it is not signed already then check-in back.

But my check-in fails as saying identical to predecessor. What is the cleartool command to undo checkout if it is identical to previous version?

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try:

```
cleartool unco
```

That is "[`undo checkout`](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_uncheckout.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-1-69)"

Now you cannot do that in the checkin command itself.

What you can do is a `cleartool diff`: if there is no difference detected, then you unco, if there are, you check in.

You have that approach detailed [in this thread](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000013751831):

> You may need to diff against the previous version, but you can use something like `diff <file> <file>@@/main/branch/version`, and if different (or whatever that diff returns if they are different), then allow the checkin to succeed). Otherwise maybe `unco -rm` the file.

Or:

> In our makefile we have a section that basically follows the following format for each file:

```
call checkin_if_changed.bat "dir1\sub\file.h"
```

> The contents of the file "`checkin_if_changed.bat`" are as follows:

```
cleartool diff -pre -dif %1
echo File: %1 diff result: %ERRORLEVEL%
goto diff%ERRORLEVEL%
:diff1
cleartool ci -c "Build box build." %1
goto end
:diff0
cleartool unco -rm %1
:end
```

> Basically we do a cleartool diff against the prev version of the file.
>   If the `cleartool diff` returns a 0 it means the files are identical, so we do an `unco -rm`.
>   If `cleartool diff` finds a difference it returns a 1, meaning the files are different, and we check it in.

Or:

> I've used the somewhat messy:

```
cleartool lsco -cvi -avo -fmt "ci -nc '%n'\nunco -rm '%n'" | cleartool
```

> If the file is identical (and fails the checkin), then it unchecks it
>   out.
>   If it isn't identical, it checks it in, then the unco command
>   fails (since it's not checked out) with an error (but continues).
>
> You can dump all of the output to a log file if you don't want to see it on
>   the command line. You can probably refine that if you need to.
>   If you have a post checkin trigger that forces you to enter a comment, then
>   change the `-nc` to `-c 'some comment'` instead.

Comment: May be i rephrase it. In the checkin command itself i need to do undo checkout if identical. Because if it is a separate command then check-in would have already failed and it will be considered as failure by CI tool.